# Python dataframe transpose time series (rows to column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to transpose (?)/ transfrom this time series:

```
values = ['Date Value   Value_30days_later',
'26.01.01   36  40.3',
'29.01.01   36  38.2',
'30.01.01   37.5    36.5',
'31.01.01   37.5    37.3',
'01.02.01   37  36.7',
'02.02.01   37.5    36.5',
'05.02.01   35  33',
'06.02.01   32.5    26.5',
'07.02.01   31  25.3',
'08.02.01   30.5    29',
'09.02.01   32.3    30.3']
```

To looking like this one

```
values = ['Date Value_-4    Value_-3    Value_-2    Value_-1    Value_0 Value_30days_later',
'01.02.01   36  36  37.5    37.5    37  36.7',
'02.02.01   36  37.5    37.5    37  37.5    36.5',
'05.02.01   37.5    37.5    37  37.5    35  33',
'06.02.01   37.5    37  37.5    35  32.5    26.5',
'07.02.01   37  37.5    35  32.5    31  25.3',
'08.02.01   37.5    35  32.5    31  30.5    29',
'09.02.01   35  32.5    31  30.5    32.3    30.3']
```

So basically converting 5 **Value** rows to columns based on **Date** and adding **Value_30days_later**
to it.

Based on the **Date** in the original time series I want to have a time series with values **0** to **-4** (the last 5 dates including the current one) and the value 30 days later.

Is there a simple function available using e.g., pandas or numpy?

Comment: The logic is not clear, please add a smaller clear example

Comment: I have limited the time series. Based on the Date in the original time series I want to have a time series with values 0 to -4 (the last 5 dates including the current one) and the value 30 days later. Does it help? I am happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now by using this function

```
    def create_lags():
    
    
    for lags in range(0,5):
        time_series['value_lag_-'+str(lag)] = time_series['value'].shift(+lag)
```

This **.shift function** does it for me.